# Sending BCH from Copay

Tags: copay

I have some BCH on copay, but I can't figure out how to send it out! If I send BTC I can easily select/type recipient(address) but in case of BCH recipient is my wallet and I can't change it? so my BCH is stucked in this wallet.
Any ideas please

Comment: Duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/76839/13866. You should edit your original question rather than repeat it. You may need to register and [merge your multiple user-identities/accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

To send Bitcoin or Bitcoin Cash from the BitPay wallet, please follow the steps below:

1. Navigate to the `Send` tab in the BitPay app and paste the address you want to send funds to into the field at top.
2. Once on the `Send` tab, there will be a screen where you will put how much you want to send. Click on the `...` option on the top right and tap on `Max` if you want to send the max amount which also includes the network/mining fees.
3. The last step will be confirming the address you want to send to and how much to send before sliding to confirm.